# jQuery sparklines - Possible to fill above line?

Tags: jquery, sparklines

Looking at the [sample graphs](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#common) on the jQuery Sparklines page, you can see that there is a `fillColor` attribute that can be used to fill in the area below a line. However, is there any way to specify a fill color for above a graph line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't have an option for that at the current time, but I'll put it on the todo list for the next version.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look into this! And for your wonderful plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the sparkline into a box that has your desired "above" color, and then set the "below" color to white. That would create that effect.

Otherwise you would have to change the source code, I am afraid. Should not be too hard.